# How to draw an overlay on Image in android?

Tags: android

I want to mark certain area in the picture like google map according to the user input.
Eg: User may give an input as BlockA then an overlay should appear in the picture where block A found. 
How is it possible in Android?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Though today is April fool day but Google won't make you fool for your searching!

Comment: Well, I have found some links. Let me try those. will be back.

Answer (score 1):

Hi arun please look on this:  http://joerg-richter.fuyosoft.com/?p=120
I think this is the best solution

Comment: Thank you very much @jinnings Let me check this link